# RSpec test not passing: Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, automated-tests, rspec-rails

I have set the following test in my ads_controller.spec.rb file:

```
describe "ads#create action" do
    it "redirects to ads#show" do
      @ad = FactoryBot.create(:ad)
      expect(response).to redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
    end
end
```

to correspond to this action in my ads controller:

```
def create
    @ad = current_user.ads.create(ad_params)
    redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
end
```

Once an ad is created, I want it to redirect to the show page for the just created ad. While this works in my browser, I clearly haven't structured my test right since I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
   Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <200: OK>
```

I've tried to troubleshoot it for a while and not sure where I'm messing things up? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can we see a [mcve] please? What's in the rest of that test file? It looks like you're probably hitting the wrong endpoint!! `FactoryBot.create` does *not* call the controller action; instead, you need to `post :create` in the spec.

Comment: For example, maybe you've got a `before { ... }` block that's hitting the `SHOW` action of your controller -- so you're actually testing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually making a call to  your create action.  You have...

```
describe "ads#create action" do
    it "redirects to ads#show" do
      @ad = FactoryBot.create(:ad)
      expect(response).to redirect_to ad_path(@ad)
    end
end
```

Which is just using FactoryBot to create the ad.  You need to do actual call to the post action.

```
RSpec.describe AdsController, type: :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    ("Add a hash of attributes valid for your ad")
  }

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid params" do

      it "redirects to the created ad" do
        post :create, params: {ad: valid_attributes}
        expect(response).to redirect_to(Ad.last)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Steve, this was really helpful, and it worked! Thanks for helping this ruby newbie ;)